# C++ DGRAM socket get the RECEIVER address

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, receiver

In C++,
    how can I get the **receiver address** of the UDP packet which I have received using recvfrom. I know that it should be the same host on which I am receiving the packet, but I need to extract it from the received packet, in order to verify something. How can I do this?

I found that one way of doing this is:

```
int r = getsockopt(receiver_sock, SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST, (struct sockaddr *) &sender_addr, (socklen_t *)&addr_len);`
```

But I get the error:

```
error: ‘SO_ORIGINAL_DST’ was not declared in this scope
```

I am using the appropriate headers

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include </usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-21/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>    
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
```

Using netfilter_ipv4 gives other errors like INT_MIN not declared. However, I think the mistake is something more fundamental rather than inclusion of proper header.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell which interface the socket received the message from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603577/how-to-tell-which-interface-the-socket-received-the-message-from)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux you want to use `IP_PKTINFO` option, see [`ip(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/ip.7.html), and the [`recvmsg(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendmsg.2.html) call.

[Stevens](http://books.google.com/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=unix+network+programming&hl=en&ei=SFa4TL2JH4SglAfhs_2ADQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) has examples of doing this but with `IP_RECVDSTADDR` and `IP_RECVIF` options that are not available on Linux.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I tried IP_PKTINFO as well.. but the real problem seems to be different. Would you mind looking at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951043/c-iptables-redirection-forming-separate-packets. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I've constructed an example that extracts the source, destination and interface addresses. For brevity, no error checking is provided. See this duplicate: [Get destination address of a received UDP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5281409/149482).

```
// sock is bound AF_INET socket, usually SOCK_DGRAM
// include struct in_pktinfo in the message "ancilliary" control data
int opt = 1;
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_PKTINFO, &opt, sizeof(opt));
// the control data is dumped here
char cmbuf[0x100];
// the remote/source sockaddr is put here
struct sockaddr_in peeraddr;
// if you want access to the data you need to init the msg_iovec fields
struct msghdr mh = {
    .msg_name = &peeraddr,
    .msg_namelen = sizeof(peeraddr),
    .msg_control = cmbuf,
    .msg_controllen = sizeof(cmbuf),
};
recvmsg(sock, &mh, 0);
for ( // iterate through all the control headers
    struct cmsghdr *cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&mh);
    cmsg != NULL;
    cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(&mh, cmsg))
{
    // ignore the control headers that don't match what we want
    if (cmsg->cmsg_level != IPPROTO_IP ||
        cmsg->cmsg_type != IP_PKTINFO)
    {
        continue;
    }
    struct in_pktinfo *pi = CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
    // at this point, peeraddr is the source sockaddr
    // pi->ipi_spec_dst is the destination in_addr
    // pi->ipi_addr is the receiving interface in_addr
}
```

Comment: What `opt` should be in line

    `setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_PKTINFO, &opt, sizeof(opt));`

?

Comment: @andrybak latest reply ever: I have added the value above. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html under Socket Options.