# C++ weird RAW sockets and iptables issue

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, iptables

With reference to [C++ iptables redirection forming separate packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951043/c-iptables-redirection-forming-separate-packets), I am facing an extremely peculiar problem now. I am trying to redirect all incoming traffic on UDP port 5060 to port 56790, and all outgoing traffic from 5060 to the port 56789. I used these iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp ! -s localhost --dport 5060 -j REDIRECT --to-port 56790
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p udp ! -s localhost --sport 5060 -j REDIRECT --to-port 56789
```

I listen on both ports using RAW SOCKETS after setting the interface to PROMISCUOUS mode using ioctl.

I see packets ONLY on 56789 i.e.SENDING side, and I do not see any packets on 56790, while wireshark shows that many packets are delivered to port 5060.

Why would this happen? Any ideas? Do you think it's a problem with iptables rules or something to do with raw sockets?

Comment: I have tried this on TWO ubuntu 10.04 machines now.. The same thing is happening. The PREROUTING REDIRECT simply is not working. What is going wrong ? !! :(

Comment: I think you should be using the "mangle" table if you are using the "-j REDIRECT" action.

Comment: In any case, iptables configuration is a topic for serverfault, voting to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

raw sockets get a copy of the original packet before modification (incoming). On outgoing it's reversed.