# What local interface was connection or packet received on?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

1. When receiving a packet on an unconnected UDP socket bound to `0.0.0.0`/`INADDR_ANY`, how can I determine what the local IP it was sent to?
2. Can I determine what interface it was received on?
3. Can this be also be done for connection-oriented sockets such as TCP?

### Update0

1. Platform is Linux, so language is irrelevant but C is native.
2. UDP sockets are bound to `INADDR_ANY` host, so `getsockname()` returns `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: What language are you programming this on?

Comment: Try this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940612/c-dgram-socket-get-the-receiver-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, have a look at [this](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/net/9810.0/0033.html). So looks like there is probably a socket option, at least in the Linux/Unix world.  What OSes does it need to work on?

Comment: I've added the platform to the Q.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to deal with the same issue on Windows platforms. My solution was to explicitly listen on all available interfaces as that way `getsockname()` works as expected.