# Receiving Data for Multiple Hosts via Linux Sockets

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I have a rather strange question.  Lately, I have been tasked with developing software to simulate a large (hundreds of nodes and up) network.  To make a long story short, we have a head-end server that communicates with each host through a predictable IP addressing scheme via Linux sockets using a mixture of broadcast and unicast.  The head-end will issue a request to a given client and will (sometimes) receive data pertaining to the command executed.  All data / commands are sent via UDP on a well-defined port.

Now, for testing purposes, we would like to use the original server binary in a virtual environment an still receive reasonable data.  For example, we would like to issue a reset command to a particular node and receive a fake notification back.  The broadcast bit is easy, as I simply have to listen in on the proper broadcast address and act accordingly.  The unicast is what has me stuck.

**The Question**

Is it possible to receive UDP requests for a large number of discrete hosts via a single (or a reduced) number of Linux sockets?  All hosts are on the same subnet and all IP addresses / hosts / network topology are known ahead of time.

**Desired Output**

Ultimately, we would like to have an app that runs on a host on the network and responds as if it were each of these discrete 'virtualized' hosts based on input datagrams.

Do note that I am not asking for someone to write me a program.  I am just simply looking for some direction as to the 'vehicle' by which this can be accomplished.

**Possible Solutions**

- RAW Sockets:  This has promise as I can trap all inbound data via a
  single socket and punt it off to a worker thread for processing and
  response.  Unfortunately, I only receive packets that are
  destined for my host IP and none of the 'fake' IPs.
- Abuse IP aliases on Linux, one for each host:  This seems to be the most direct approach but it feels like duck hunting with a bazooka.  It has the added benefit of appearing to 'be' the host for any other forms of communication, I just worry that creating 400+ aliases might be a bit much for our bastard-child of a Linux environment.  As an added complication, the hosts do change based on configuration and can be in any manner of states (up, down, command processing, etc.).

The source code of the server is to be treated as immutable for the purpose of our testing.  I fully expect this will be impossible with the constraints given, but someone may have an idea of how to accomplish this as, quite frankly, I have never done anything of this sort before.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, using a combination of both of caf's solutions, I was able to have my cake and eat it too.  I was also heavily influenced by

[Python/iptables: Capturing all UDP packets and their original destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038727/python-iptables-capturing-all-udp-packets-and-their-original-destination)

which is a Python example, but does show how I can 'cheat' the packets back to a single interface, negating the need for maintenance of many sockets.  That question is well worth the read and contains a lot of good information.  For compactness, though, I will restate part of it below.

Hopefully it can help someone else down the road.

**Part 1 - Host Configuration**

As stated in the above question, we can use a combination of `iptables` and `ip` routes to redirect the packets to loopback for processing.  This was not stated in my original question, but it is acceptable for the 'simulator' to run on the head-end host itself and not be a discrete node on the network.  To do this, we mark each packet via `iptables` and then route it to `lo` based on said mark.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p udp --dport 27333 -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

In my case, I only need traffic to a certain port so my `iptables` rule has been adjusted accordingly from the original.

**Part 2 - Software**

As caf stated in his post, the real trick is to use `IP_TRANSPARENT` and a raw socket.  Raw sockets are necessary in order to get the original source / destination IP addresses.  One gotchya that took me a while was the use of `IPPROTO_UDP` in the call to socket().  Even though this is a raw socket, it will strip out the Ethernet header.  A lot of code online shows the calculation of the IP header offset using something similar to the following:

```
struct iphdr* ipHeader = (struct iphdr *)(buf + sizeof(ethhdr));
```

Offsetting by ethhdr (which is stripped) will give you some rather entertaining garbage data.  With that particular header removed, the necessary IP header is simply the first structure in the buffer.

**The Test Code**

Below you will find a proof-of-concept example.  It is no way fully functional or complete.  In particular, no checking in done on the incoming packets for malicious data (ex. format string exploits in the payload, pointer math problems, malformed / malicious packets, etc).

Note that the code binds to `lo` specifically.  This does not mean that we will only get packets destined for one of our 'fake' hosts (other services use loobpack, too).  Additional checking / filtering is required to get *only* the packets we want.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  //Set up listening socket
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  struct iphdr* ipHeader;
  struct udphdr* udpHeader;
  int listenSock = 0;
  char data[65536];
  static int is_transparent = 1;
  std::string device = "lo";

  //Initialize listening socket
  if ((listenSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0) {
      printf("Error creating socket\n");
      return 1;
  }

  setsockopt(listenSock, SOL_IP, IP_TRANSPARENT, &is_transparent, sizeof(is_transparent));
  setsockopt(listensock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTO_DEVICE, device.c_str(), device.size());
  memset(&serverAddr, 0x00, sizeof(serverAddr));
  memset(&data, 0x00, sizeof(data));

  //Setup server address
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(27333);

  //Bind and listen
  if (bind(listenSock, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0) {
      printf("Error binding socket\n");
      return 1;
  }

  while (1) {

      //Accept connection
      recv(listenSock, data, 65536, 0);

      //Get IP header
      ipHeader = (struct iphdr*)(data);

      //Only grab UDP packets (17 is the magic number for UDP protocol)
      if ((unsigned int)ipHeader->protocol == 17) {

        //Get UDP header information
        udpHeader = (struct udphdr*)(data + (ipHeader->ihl * 4));

        //DEBUG
        struct sockaddr_in tempDest;
        struct sockaddr_in tempSource;
        char* payload = (char*)(data + ipHeader->ihl * 4) + sizeof(struct udphdr));

        memset(&tempSource, 0x00, sizeof(tempSource));
        memset(&tempDest, 0x00, sizeof(tempDest));
        tempSource.sin_addr.s_addr = ipHeader->saddr;
        tempDest.sin_addr.s_addr = ipHeader->daddr;

        printf("Datagram received\n");
        printf("Source IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(tempSource.sin_addr));
        printf("Dest IP  : %s\n", inet_ntoa(tempDest.sin_addr));
        printf("Data     : %s\n", payload);
        printf("Port     : %d\n\n", ntohs(udpHeader->dest));
      }
  }
}
```

**Further Reading**

Some very helpful links are below.

http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-in-c-using-linux-sockets-bsd-part-2/

http://bert-hubert.blogspot.com/2012/10/on-binding-datagram-udp-sockets-to-any.html

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use your second option - add all the IP addresses to the host, then bind to `INADDR_ANY` address.  This would mean you could use just one socket.

An alternative is to set the `IP_TRANSPARENT` socket option on your socket, which will then allow your application to bind to non-local addresses (you would route the networks containing those addresses through the machine that your application is running on).  This method does require one socket per address, though.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the response.  I assume that, with your second option, there is no way to specify multiple binding addresses?  I have seen examples of people re-binding sockets, but I assume this cannot occur simultaneously?  I also did some looking, it appears that IP_TRANSPARENT does not work with raw sockets.  Is there a technical reason for this?  It seems like grabbing all non-local packets via a  raw socket would let me have my cake and eat it too.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot have a socket bound to multiple addresses at the same time.  I don't really see a problem with having many sockets, though.  Just use `epoll()` to wait for events on them.