# Python socket bind 0.0.0.0, inspect incoming message

Tags: python, sockets

I have a socket according to:

```
self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
self.socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 67)) # Listen on port 67
```

Now, the socket listening on all interfaces at port 67. I wait for some message:

```
message, address = self.socket.recvfrom(8192) # Blocking
```

When a message is received, I would like to send a broadcast response at port 68 on the same interface that was receiving the message.

The question is: Is there some way to inspect the message and determine which network interface that was receiving the message, and if it is, how can I send a response and provide that interface for transport?

Running at Windows, Python 3.4.

Comment: Possibily related - [How to tell which interface the socket received the message from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603577/how-to-tell-which-interface-the-socket-received-the-message-from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You could only distinguish between the interfaces if you'd bind to each IP address separately (which would open a socket for each interface).

EDIT: as @jweyrich pointed out in the comments below, on Windows a socket option called [IP_PKTINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh285668(v=vs.85).aspx) (of course [Linux also](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip)) could provide the information - *if* it implemented

Comment: You can, strictly talking about UDP - see [IP_PKTINFO](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip)

Comment: indeed, my bad - [for windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh285668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Just not sure this would work over the Python's socket abstraction - I haven't read the code to know if it internally uses `WSARecvMsg`.

Comment: OpenBSD doesn't have it, NetBSD has issues (http://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-net/2013/09/22/msg004252.html), OSX didn't last time I looked (10.7), IOS??? ....

Comment: OP is running on Windows, if he doesn't care about portability, the socket option may solve the problem - yet I doubt Python's implementation does use `WSARecvMsg` internally on Windows.

Comment: @jweyrich, thanks, I missed that part, thats *my bad* actually. If you don't post this as an answer, I'll update my own in a few minutes.

Comment: No worries. I didn't notice that bit as well, at least not until your 1st reply. Feel free to update your answer. If it works, it's still necessary to parse that extra information (since Python's doesn't provide the necessary structures) - A quick search revealed [someone already did it](http://carnivore.it/2012/10/12/python3.3_sendmsg_and_recvmsg).